# global variable in javascript not working; loses data

Tags: javascript, scope, global

```
var feed;
$.getJSON('short.json', function(data) {
    feed = data.items;
    console.log(feed);
    });
console.log(feed);
```

I have this short code written above. I am expecting feed to be a global variable but once it comes out the function, it's undefined again. It prints out an object when inside. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you sure data.items is not undefined?

Comment: That'll happen with **async** calls in JavaScript. `getJSON` is still processing when your log gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `getJSON()` call is asynchronous. It won't run until AFTER the second `console.log();`